# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i} = \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, solution-verification

We're supposed to give two solutions, one using an integral and one without an integral.
My solution using an integral is the following:

$\int_0^n \frac{1}{i} dx \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} \leq \int_1^{n+1} \frac{1}{i}  dx$

$\implies \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} =
\Theta(\ln(n)) $ (Is this that obvious that i don't need proof? I don't quite understand this one myself, it was given as a logical result of the integral criterium in our book.)

$\ln(n) < n$ for positive n.

We substitute $n$ with  $\sqrt{n^2}$:

$\ln(\sqrt{n^2}) < \sqrt{n^2}$

$2\cdot \ln(\sqrt{n}) < 2\cdot \sqrt{n}$

$\implies \ln(n) = \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$

And therefore our sum is $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$ as well.

Is this solution correct? I only used the integral to conclude that we could also just show $\ln(n) = \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$.

Would this count as the solution using an integral? How would the solution without an integral look like?

Comment: The main idea is correct. Just need to fix some stuffs in the integral.

Comment: It is a solution and it uses the integral, so I'd count it

Comment: Which part of the integral needs fixing? Could you point me in a direction of a solution without an integral?

Comment: The integral shouldn't start at $x=0$ and $x$ should appear rather than $i$. Below you find a solution without integral (by Hagen von Eitzen).

Comment: The integral starts at $x = 0$ in our book. I'm not quite sure. Thank you for making me aware of the $x$ instead of $i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a solutoin without integral, note that for $n\in\Bbb N$,
$$\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{ n-1}=\frac1{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt {n-1}}\ge \frac1{2\sqrt {n}}.$$
Then by telescoping
$$ 2\sqrt n-2\sqrt 0\ge \sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt i}\ge \sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{ i}.$$

Comment: I think you mean $1/(\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n-1}) \ge 1/(2\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, thanks I just saw that too

Comment: How did you arrive at the first equation? I understand that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} \geq \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$ But i'm not quite sure how you arrived at $2\sqrt{n} - 2\sqrt{0}$ and what it has to do with the first equation.

Comment: I think i understand now, you want something comparable to the fraction and used $-2\sqrt{0}$ to get the equation without the fraction. But how is $2\sqrt{n}$ implicitly bigger than $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} $ ? I don't see the connection here.